# Validating columns only numerical values should be there

Tags: vba, excel

i have written a code

```
  Sub CellCheck()
  Dim Header(1 To 2) As String
   Header(1) = "Header1" 'header name
   Header(2) = "Header2"  'header name
   Dim rCell As Range
   Dim sMyString As String
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
   Set rCell = Range("A:A)
   If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) = False And _
   IsError(rCell.Value) = False Then
   'assuming Error_sheet already present 
   Sheets("error_sheet").Range("A" & row).Value = "There are " & 
   Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumeric(r) & " Rows with error in column" & 

   Header(i)
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
   Set rCell = Range("B:B)
   If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) = False And _
   IsError(rCell.Value) = False Then
   Sheets("error_sheet").Range("A" & row).Value = "There are " & 
   Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumeric(r) & " Rows with error in column" & 
   Header(i)
  End sub
```

[image]

To validate both the columns must have numerical values only, if any of the column contains Text,Special character or so, The cell no. of that column/s should appear in a different sheet called Error_sheet. Blanks are fine in both the columns. Moreover all non-blank cells of column 'Header1' should have same values i.e. if A1 = 46, all cells of column 'Header1' should have 46 only. if no macro should make the appear in the Error_sheet with cell no. and same checks should be performed in column 'Header2' as well

Comment: I suggested an edit which appears to have disappeared. You have duplicate code at the bottom, these references  Range("A:A) and Range("B:B) are incomplete. Also, i think End Ifs are missing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. There were a few issues with your original code so see below my answer for some areas that were problematic.

```
Sub CellCheck()
Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsE As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim ct1 As Long, ct2 As Long, m1 As Long, m2 As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String

Set wsA = ActiveSheet
Set wsE = Worksheets("error_sheet")

lastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max( _
    wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
    wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
Set rng = wsA.Range(wsA.Cells(2, 1), wsA.Cells(lastRow, 2))

m1 = wsA.Cells(2, 1).Value
m2 = wsA.Cells(2, 2).Value

For Each cell In rng
    'skip first row
    If cell.Row <> 1 Then
        If cell.Column = 1 Then
            If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then ct1 = ct1 + 1
            If cell.Value <> m1 and cell.Value <> "" Then str1 = _
                CombStr(str1, Replace(cell.Address, "$", ""))
        ElseIf cell.Column = 2 Then
            If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then ct2 = ct2 + 1
            If cell.Value <> m2 and cell.Value <> "" Then str2 = _
                CombStr(str2, Replace(cell.Address, "$", ""))
        End If
    End If
Next cell

wsE.Range("A" & 1) = _
"There are " & ct1 & " rows with errors in column " & wsA.Cells(1, 1)
wsE.Range("A" & 2) = _
"There are " & ct2 & " rows with errors in column " & wsA.Cells(1, 2)
If str1 <> "" Then wsE.Range("A" & 3) = _
"The following cells in column A did not match the value in cell A2: " & str1
If str2 <> "" Then wsE.Range("A" & 4) = _
"The following cells in column B did not match the value in cell B2: " & str2

'put any additional code you need here

End Sub

Function CombStr(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
If str1 = "" And str2 <> "" Then
    CombStr = str2
ElseIf str1 <> "" And str2 = "" Then
    CombStr = str1
ElseIf str1 <> "" And str2 <> "" Then
    CombStr = str1 & ", " & str2
End If
End Function
```

- `IsNumeric` won't work with a range, only a single value, so you would need to loop through values in a range and check them individually
- `Range("A:A)` and `Range("B:B)` would not evaluate correctly (missing a `"`)
- `row` and `r` are never defined or assigned values anywhere
- The `ErrorHandle` section is never defined
- Regarding `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumeric(r)`, `IsNumeric` is not a worksheet function (`=ISNUMBER()` is) so it doesn't need `Application.WorksheetFunction.` in front of it, and this expression would just return a `True` or `False`, not the actual number like I think you wanted
- No `End If`'s for your `If`'s
- `sMyString` doesn't seem to be used

Comment: Thanks for the code and explaining the issues with my code. This code perfectly validates whether both the column s have numerical values or not, But  this thing  if A1 = 46, all cells of column 'Header1' should have 46 only. if no macro should make the appear in the Error_sheet with cell no. and same checks should be performed in column 'Header2' as well

Comment: has been missed i guess could you please provide me the code for this as well.

Comment: I assume you mean A2 (since A1 will be Header1)? I edited my answer to do this check and to list the cells that didn't match on the error_sheet.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah A2 only, my bad ! This code is working absolutely fine but i have further code too to run just after the execution of provided code and when i do so it shows only comments can appear after a function. And one more thing this code consider blanks as mismatch, Could you neglect the same ?

Comment: I added an extra `And` that will make the matching ignore blanks. For adding additional code, you'd have to add it between `"The following cells in column B did not match the value in cell B2: " & str2` and `End Sub` (I put a comment in the code above where you would add it). The Function tacked on the end there is technically a different thing entirely from this Sub so anything put after the Function would be unrelated.